# Sendmail attach all files in directory

Tags: shell, sendmail

I want to send mail and attach all files in directory.
Below doesn't work

```
sendMail -a | find . -name '*.*'
```

Comment: What is your `sendMail`? The Linux [`sendmail`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sendmail.sendmail) does not have an `-a` parameter. Also I’m pretty sure you should replace `|` but I cannot say what to put there instead without knowledge of your `sendMail` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try mutt

```
echo "body" | mutt -s "subject" -a attachment0 attachment1 [...] -- my@email.com
```